# How to create a bijection from the union of the set natural numbers and square root 2 to the set of natural numbers?

Tags: cardinals

Since $\Bbb N$ and ${\sqrt2}$ are each countable sets, I see that the union is also countable. From this and the fact that $\Bbb N$ union ${\sqrt2}$ is infinite we know there exists a bijection to $\Bbb N$

I understand why such a bijection exists, but i'm not sure how to create the actual bijection itself?

If we let an element in the union be the smallest element we can show that it is impossible for two elements to be the smallest element in that set so that it would be one to one. and then because it is infinite, it is also onto. Is this correct?

Comment: The two sets are indeed countably infinite. But I think you are being asked to give an *explicit* bijection.  Suppose we decide to let $f(\sqrt{2})=1$. Then we could let $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$f:\Bbb N\cup\{\sqrt{2}\}\to\Bbb N$$
by $f(\sqrt{2})=1$ and $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Its inverse is the map
$$g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\cup\{\sqrt{2}\}$$
defined by $g(n)=n-1$ for $n\geq 2$ and $g(1)=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Okay, then if I had something similar but the union was between the set of natural numbers and the set containing $\sqrt2$ and$\pi$ would I let $f(\sqrt2)=1$ and $f(\pi)=2$ and $f(n)=n+2$ ?

Comment: @user319635 Yes, that would work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. If it were the other way around and I was to go from the set of natural numbers to the set of natural numbers excluding some values how would I go about this?

Comment: Is it different if instead of $N$ union $\sqrt2$ is is $N$ excluding $\sqrt2$?

Comment: @user319635 Since $\sqrt{2}\notin\Bbb N$ I am not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh exactly, I should have thought of a different example. Let me change that, If it was $N$ excluding some value in $N$, like 2?

Comment: Or even better, what if it was $N$ excluding all the odd numbers?

Comment: Define $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N-\{2\}$ by $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=3$, $f(3)=4$, $f(4)=5$, and so on.

Comment: Define $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N-\Bbb N_{odd}$ by $f(n)=2n$.